# Magento 2 get custom collection data in view/frontend/web/template html file for payment block on checkout page

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have a collection and I have created a helper function that returns all values in an array.

Now I need all those value in **`vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\payment-method\list.html`** file.

Also, I want the same value on the HTML file for payment method title display.

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

payment-method\list.html is the knock js Html template files and as per knock Html template file has its respective js file.

If you want to get custom collection data at `list.html` file then on Js variable you have to save to your collection data as json. Suggest to you create phtml files & Block class. On window js variable like `window.custom.collection =<?php echo {YourHelperClassFunction}` ?>;

Then using `list.html` js view js  file [`Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/list`](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/list.js#L22).Then at list.js file fetch data at new function and call this function to at  `list.html`.

Comment: Thanks amit for suggesting me good approach.  I will try and let you know.

Comment: Thanks Amit, it works